# An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll Additional information: Keyword not supported: 'username'

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have an assignment due next week and I have literally hit a mind block.. Some assistance would be much appreciated. I keep getting this response An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll  Additional information: Keyword not supported: 'username'.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb"/>
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>

    <connectionStrings>

      <add
   name="VoteWithDEV"
   connectionString="Data Source=k2mmbsouh0.database.windows.net;
        Initial Catalog=VoteWithDEV;Persist Security Info=True;Username=patrickmcmu11an;Password=Jordan123"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>

    <appSettings>
      <add key="ConnectionStringName" value="VoteWithDEV"/>
    </appSettings>

  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: `User ID` is the correct term for your username in a connection string IIRC

Comment: In your connection string `Username=patrickmcmu11an;` should be `User ID=patrickmcmu11an;`

Comment: Once this has been changed guys im still getting..

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll

Additional information: One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:


about to lose my mind

Comment: Any details about one or more validation errors ?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' occurred in System.Configuration.dll

Additional information: Configuration system failed to initialize

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>

    <startup>

      <connectionStrings>

        <add
     name="VoteWithDEV"
     connectionString="Data Source=k2mmbsouh0.database.windows.net;
        Initial Catalog=VoteWithDEV;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=patrickmcmu11an;;Password=Jordan123"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
      </connectionStrings>

      <appSettings>
        <add key="ConnectionStringName" value="VoteWithDEV"/>
      </appSettings>
    </startup>
  </configSections>
</configuration>

Comment: The XML in your comment is malformed - you have wrapped everything in the `configSections` section - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fm3vT.png

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll

Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Comment: @stuartd any ideas? losing my mind

Comment: Have you enabled remote access to the DB through the Azure Managment Portal?

Comment: I am trying to figure that out now, fingers crossed

Answer (score 1):

Remove appsettings block and as mentioned use USER ID , also replace Persist Security Info=True with Integrated Security=false.

Comment: `PersistSecurityInfo` != `IntegratedSecurity`